# Unity2D: How to lock my game for a certain amount of time sort of like candy crush

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I have a 2d topdown rpg game, and I wanted to know if there was a way of locking my game for a certain amount of time (countdown) when my player loses all of his hearts (lives). And no matter what the user can not access my game until the countdown has complete. Just like candy crush when you lose all of your lives. So far I've got a panel that slides down, saying GameOver, when the player dies (when all of his hearts are gone). But I'm not really sure how to put a lock on my game for a certain amount of time, I also want the user to sill go back to the main menu even if the game is still lock. Like I said before I want it similar to candy crush saga where if the player loses live then they will have to wait a certain amount of time to play the game.

This script is the health script of my player, as you can see my game over panel is linked to this as well as my UI manager:

```
public int curHealth;
public int maxHealth = 3;
Vector3 startPosition;
public PlayerHealth playerhealthRef;
float counter;
public Animator anima; // drag the panel in here again
private UI_ManagerScripts UIM;
private PlayerScript ps;


void Start ()
{
    curHealth = maxHealth;
    startPosition = transform.position;
    ps = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlayerScript").GetComponent <PlayerScript> ();

}


void Update ()
{

    if (curHealth > maxHealth) {
        curHealth = maxHealth;
    }
    if (curHealth <= 0) {

        Die ();
    }
}

void Awake()
{
    UIM = GameObject.Find ("UIManager").GetComponent<UI_ManagerScripts> ();
}

void Die(){

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("Highscore")) {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Highscore") < ps.Score) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Highscore", ps.Score);
        }
    } else 
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Highscore", ps.Score);
    }

    UIM.EnableBoolAnimator(anima);
}

public void Damage(int dmg)
{
    curHealth -= dmg;
    Reset();
}

void Reset ()
{
    transform.position = startPosition;
    GotoMouse.target = startPosition;

      } 
  }
```

This is my UImanager script:

```
public AudioClip swooshSound;

public void DisableBoolAnimator(Animator anim)
{
    anim.SetBool ("IsDisplayed", false);
}

public void EnableBoolAnimator(Animator anim)
{
    anim.SetBool ("IsDisplayed", true);
}

public void NavigateTo(int scene)
{
    Application.LoadLevel (scene);
}

public void ExitGame()
{
    Application.Quit ();
}

public void PauseGame()
{
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (swooshSound, transform.position);
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}

public void UnPauseGame()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1;
     }
 }
```

Thank you :)

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/713220/how-can-i-make-a-life-system-like-candy-crush.html

Comment: Thank you but I just want to lock my game once all of my players lives are wasted.

Comment: what do you mean by "lock"?

Comment: I believe that you want to add a check if(lives != 0) {Application.LoadLevel (scene)} ? In other words, force the player to get more lives, right?

Comment: Just use **Invoke** for timers in unity.

Comment: Like you can't access it, like candy crush when you run out of lives this [pop up] (http://imgur.com/KDkTjd2), I want to do that, but I don't know how! Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the player wait for a certain amount of time, you should save a [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) to a file.  Then, when the player tries to play, have the game check if the date/time is **later** than the date/time saved to the file.  Something like this:

```
//For saving the file when the player loses
File.WriteAllText("path_to_file", DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString());
//For checking to see if the player can play
if(Convert.ToDateTime(File.ReadAllText("path_to_file")) < DateTime.Now)
{
    //Allow player to play
}
else { 
    //Tell player they can't play 
}
```

Then change `DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)` to however many hours you want the player to wait, or you can change it to `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)` to however many minutes you want the player to wait.  Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thank you for replying,  just have one question should I add this to my player health script or make a new script  Thank you again

Comment: You can do whatever you want with it.  I would add the `File.WriteAllText()` to the `Die` method.  Have the method check to see if the player has any more lives, and if they don't, have it call `WriteAllText()`.  Then, add the part of code that checks the file to a script that manages the clicking of your play button.  Have it check if the player has any more lives, and if they don't, check the file to see if the game should tell them they must wait, or if the time is past the time saved in the file, allow them to play.  Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you out :)